# Apache common codec in java from string to hex and viceversa

Tags: java, string, hex, apache-commons-codec

I am trying to encode a string in hex and then convert it again to string. For this purpose I'm using the apache common codec. In particular I have defined the following methods:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.DecoderException;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;
public String toHex(byte[] byteArray){

    return Hex.encodeHexString(byteArray);    

}

public byte[]  fromHex(String hexString){

    byte[] array = null;

    try {
        array = Hex.decodeHex(hexString.toCharArray());
    } catch (DecoderException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SecureHash.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return array;

}
```

The strange thing is that I do not get the same initial string when converting back. More strangely, the byte array I get, it's different from the initial byte array of the string.
The small test program that I wrote is the following:

```
    String uno = "uno";
    byte[] uno_bytes = uno.getBytes();

    System.out.println(uno);
    System.out.println(uno_bytes);

    toHex(uno_bytes);
    System.out.println(hexed);

    byte [] arr = fromHex(hexed);
    System.out.println(arr.toString());
```

An example of output is the following:

```
uno            #initial string
[B@1afe17b     #byte array of the initial string
756e6f         #string representation of the hex 
[B@34d46a      #byte array of the recovered string
```

There is also another strange behaviour. The byte array ([B@1afe17b) is not fixed, but is different from run to run of the code, but I cannot understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print a byte array, the `toString()` representation does not contain the contents of the array. Instead, it contains a type indicator (`[B` means byte array) and the hashcode. The hashcode will be different for two distinct byte arrays, even if they contain the same contents. See [`Object.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) and [`Object.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) for further information.

Instead, you maybe want to compare the arrays for equality, using:

```
System.out.println("Arrays equal: " + Arrays.equals(uno_bytes, arr));
```